# Format of JSON payload in Azure Logic App HTTP Request trigger

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have been trying to create a very simple Logic App in Azure but I keep failing because it does not seem to be accepting my JSON.

Using my payload

```
{
  "userPrincipalName": "notmy@ddress.com",
  "computerName": "MyComputername"
}
```

I created the trigger

[image: Logic App Trigger]

I then use the values of my payload in my response:

[image: Log App Response]

Save it and then I POST using [Hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it) to the HTTP POST URL in the request.

[image: Request]

[image: Response]

So why the heck is the value not used? I'm not able to use any of the values I'm sending.

Answer (score 0):

Okay..  that was dumb..

I had to add the Content-Type header to the POST:

[image]